# Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account. after app publish

Tags: java, android, authorization, required

i have problem because i published my first application on google play but i can't download it because i get: *Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account* I tried to download it on 3 devices and 4 google accounts but problem doesn't disappear.

Comment: no, im still looking for solution

Comment: Same happened to me today, we communicated with google and they said it's issue on their side and they are working on a fix..

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372185/authentication-error-for-google-account-when-installing-my-application

Comment: Does solution from this topic(alpha test) work?

Comment: Morisson: It did for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your app description. Add space as last character should be enough.