# Authentication error for Google account when installing my Application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I am able to use Google Play and download/install apps. But when I try to install my app which is already published and visible on Google Play store, I keep getting the following error:

> Authentication is required. You need to sign in to your Google
>   Account.

I have tried it on different android devices, reset the Google account on the mobile device and re-logged in. I still end up getting the same error only for my app.

Please advice if you have encountered a similar error. Lots of remedies available when searched for the said error message but those are when all apps are not downloadable. My issue is localized only to my app.

The app(a simple game) is Android based and made with Unity.

Link to the app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.CubeBoy.FlyBox

Comment: well do you use `ConnectionResult` to resolve the sign-in issue with google play services?

Comment: No. I compiled everything from Unity itself. Didn't write anything separate for android class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, posting the final APK to production stage straight away causes the above mentioned error.

Ensure the following:

1. Post your initial APK to Alpha first.
2. Set up a Google Group account for testing and add it under "Manage list of testers"

Answer (score 1):

This article was great an is definitely bookmarked. My only suggestion is that you add the following: 
Here'e what worked for me - after nearly a day of troubleshooting:

1. Follow this tutorial EXACTLY:
   https://help.gamesalad.com/hc/en-us/articles/203536123-7-6-In-App-Purchases-IAP-for-Google-Play
2. Note that in this tutorial you publish an alpha testing version and add testers. Also note that the testers must have different gmail accounts than the owner of the Developer Console. So, IF THE APP IS NOT PUBLISHED, ALL TESTERS will be blocked.
3. If the app is published and the users are listed as testers, ensure that the testers go to the link specified in Console -> Apk Tab -> Manange List of Testers -> Share the following link with your testers. If no link is present yet, then you cannot begin testing.
4. If all of the above is done, then remove all accounts from your device, restart, and then add only the tester's account to the device. For example, if myTester@gmail.com then on device go to settings-> Accounts -> Google -> Click each account and select "remove account" -> Restart device -> Go to settings -> Accounts -> Add Account -> Select a Google account and enter credentials. As stated in the tutorial, this account CANNOT BE THE SAME as the Developer's Console owner.
5. The last check would be to try and sign into Google Play and see what account comes up. If not, the account credentials may be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Play also told me it was incompatible with my devices.

I used keshk's advise and posted it as a Beta version first. Then I chose to lift it over to Production. (button to the right of the version) Then it worked immediately to install it and the incompatible warning was gone.

No need to add any testers etc.

PS I don't know exactly what text is on the English version of the button as I get it in Swedish.

Answer (score 0):

I make some research. That's error can display when APK version not the same than on the production. For example, production version have 0.1, you build new version 0.2. You will get that message, until upload new version to google.